# Can a RDBMS connect to a remote server, execute a select query and copy them into a local table just with SQL commands?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, select, remote

I'm sorry it may sound stupid but I've been wondering about how multiple databases are automated before the virtualization era. Can a DB Adminsitrator make a stored procedure to get data from a remote RDBMS and select them into a local table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, in SQL Server at least you can set up a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) to other SQL Servers, Oracle, MySQL etc. and pull data from them. There are other approaches as well (such as [OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx)). An example would be:

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.localtable FROM OtherServer.database.dbo.TableName;
```

In Oracle I think the equivalent is [database link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5005.htm#SQLRF01205) but I confess that I have never used it.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, you can use a [database link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/glossary.htm#sthref4135) object to do it.

`CREATE TABLE localtable as (SELECT * FROM remote_table@link_name)`

Answer (score 2):

Linked Server & Openquery suggested by @Aaron is simplest and fastest option for sql server to connect to remote server, but just to present the variety, you can also develop a [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917%28SQL.105%29.aspx) package for sql 2005 & above or a [DTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933550%28SQL.80%29.aspx) package for sql 2000, these are ETL tools of SQL server

Comment: SSIS/DTS seems overkill for a single table here and there.

Comment: indeed, i agree with you about this issue, in the OP its mentioned `I've been wondering about how multiple databases are automated` and `to get data from a remote RDBMS` , so incase @ugurcode wants to know different ways.