# Methodology & Architecture to Create ETL Process

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, etl, business-intelligence

What book or webpage can I read the architecture and methodology for creating ETL process?

In other words, I'm looking for "how to do it" to create a ETL process when you have many source system to be involved and you also have a data warehouse.

Comment: are you looking for a generic way, i mean designing an ETL process regardless of the tool or you want to develop an ETL package of a specific tool, because every tool is different and in your case you mentioned sqlserver as a tag, so you might be looking for [DTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917688.aspx) **sql 2000** or [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917(v=sql.105).aspx) **sql 2005 & above**

Comment: The answer is "designing an ETL process regardless of the tool". I would like to use sql code only, no ETL application like SSIS or Informatica.

Comment: for "designing an ETL process regardless of the tool" , books or courses by  [Ralph Kimball](http://www.kimballgroup.com/html/books.html) very useful for generic concepts just like @Codek & @N West suggested, you also have the [TDWI](http://tdwi.org/Forms/Search-Results.aspx?query=ETL&collection=TDWI_Web) search for ETL papers. --- point 2 to use sql code only, [Linked servers & Openquery](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19098/can-a-rdbms-connect-to-a-remote-server-execute-a-select-query-and-copy-them-int/19118#19118) will help you transfer Data to SQL with sql code only

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend reading [The Data Warehouse Toolkit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471200247) by Ralph Kimball. Goes through the theory,  with some good examples, and will leave you with a solid understanding of the theory. Then you can look at the tools themselves.

If you're looking for something to build your ETL process, Pentaho have something called the "Star Modeller" which lets you model your dwh, and it then builds the ETL/cubes etc.  But it's pretty new and far from complete - worth keeping an eye on though.

Comment: He also wrote [The Data Warehouse ETL Toolkit](http://www.amazon.com/The-Data-Warehouse-ETL-Toolkit/dp/0764567578) which is a through explanation of ETL architecture.